# Graceful degradation across Salesforce editions

Tags: managed-package, custom

I've a managed package installed in all Salesforce editions. Recently, I decided to add some features using the new Custom Permissions feature, which is not available in Professional or Group editions.

Now the managed package can not be installed in either PE or GE organizations.

What I would like to happen is to disable this particular feature for PE/GE orgs, but rest of the functionality should be available as they were earlier (hence Graceful Degradation).

Is this possible to do? What are the best practices in supporting multiple editions without maintaining separate code base?